# imap_open fails giving Unable to create selectable TCP socket

Tags: php, imap

I have the following code

```
$mbox = imap_open("{mail.mydomain.com:143/imap/notls}INBOX", "newsletter@mydomain.com","xxxxxxx");

 if ($mbox)
 {
  echo "connected";
  imap_close($mbox);
 }
 else
 {
  echo "not connected :<br>" . imap_last_error();
 }
```

It give this output

```
   not connected :
   Unable to create selectable TCP socket (1919 >= 1024)
```

I am able to telnet to the domain, using
       telnet mail.mydomain.com 443

```
   A LOGIN username password
   A OK LOGIN Ok
```

What is wrong with my PHP code?

Comment: Perhaps creating sockets is restricted in your build/environment? I don't believe that to be a problem with your code.

Comment: How can I check this?

Comment: I don't know PHP, so I can't help you with the specifics. :(  There is a lot of sample IPHP MAP code here on SO, and it all seems to look fairly similar to yours.

Comment: Looking more carefully, it looks like your system returned an FD with a handle/integer higher than 1024, and PHP doesn't think it can use select on it.  (presumably PHP was built on a system where FD_SETSIZE was 1024...)  This appears to be a PHP Build issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears PHP must be recompiled with a larger FD_SETSIZE.  It appears to be mismatched to your system.  Your system returns handle larger than 1024, but PHP thinks socket handles can only go up to 1024.